# MVC 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to send the request to controller but the console returns 500 error. What is the problem here?

Thanks in advance!

JS CODE:

```
    $('.delete_btn').on('click', function () {
        $.get("/List/Delete", { param: $(this).data('id') }, function (data) {
            $('#modal_window').replaceWith('<div id="modal_window">' + data + '</div>');
            $('#modal_window').show();
        });
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
  //DELETE ITEM
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        H_Table item = db_connection.H_Table.Find(id);
        db_connection.H_Table.Remove(item);
        db_connection.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

SCREENSHOT:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing wrong paramert name.

Change your parameter name from **param** to **id** in ajax request.

```
  $('.delete_btn').on('click', function () {
           $.get("/List/Delete", { id: $(this).data('id') }, function (data) {
               $('#modal_window').replaceWith('<div id="modal_window">' + data + '</div>');
               $('#modal_window').show();
           });
       });
```

And your button must have **data-id** attribute. like this

```
<input type="button" class="delete_btn" value="Test" data-id="7" />
```

Comment: can show screenshot of your console error or network tab. and How you are getting id value.

Comment: It is up there.

Answer (score 0):

You are performing delete operation so you need to make post or delete request and in controller you need to decorate action method by [httpPost].